# yii2 query multiple keyword

Tags: php, sql, yii2

I have this problem with query in yii2.

All is fine when I use this line:

```
$query = Course::find()->where(['name' => ['sample2', 'sample3', 'sample4']])->all();
```

the problem is when I store the keywords in a variable, like:

```
$name_list = "'sample2', 'sample3', 'sample4'";
$query = Course::find()->where(['name' => [$name_list]])->all();
```

Nothing will happen.

Thank you.

Comment: `where` isn't smart enough. It will assemble the final sql statement based on the type of the value passed to it. Just do as your first style.

Comment: is there any way to achieve it? thanks.

Comment: You have to change the source code to achieve it.

Comment: You want to `find in array or find_in_set or like query`? Unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

Hi bro I just found out the possible problem with your query

first you used an array here:

```
$query = Course::find()->where(['name' => ['sample2', 'sample3', 'sample4']])->all();
```

then you just used string here :

```
$name_list = "'sample2', 'sample3', 'sample4'";
$query = Course::find()->where(['name' => [$name_list]])->all();
```

if you want to take a try this code:

```
$name_list =array('sample2', 'sample3', 'sample4');
$query = Course::find()->where(['name' => $name_list])->all();
```

Comment: thanks @Dee [$name_list] this line should not put inside a bracket co'z it's already an array. thank you